# In python, how to iterator all 'types'?

Tags: python, python-2.7

In python, how to iterator all types?

[image]

Like the image above, there are many types in python, but 'types' is not iterable.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\...\abc.py", line 189, in <module>
    for t in types:
TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable
```

Is there any way to iterate the types without manually specify them?

Comment: `for name in dir(types):`, or in this case, `for name in types.__all__`? Why do you need to iterate over all names in the `types` module? The module does not contain all possible Python types.

Comment: Note that `types` does not contain *all* types; and there is nothing that will give you all available types.

Comment: Well, you *can* get all types by searching the type hierarchy with the `__subclasses__` method of type objects, but you usually shouldn't. It won't pick up old-style classes, new types could come into existence at any time (usually when new modules are imported), and if you're doing it in an actual program, that usually indicates that your program's design has a serious problem.

Comment: I was checking a type for ob = TestClass() so that "isinstance(ob, types.xxxType)" is True and "isinstance(TestClass, types.xxxType)" is False. I have tried a few types like InstanceType and ObjectType, but haven't found one. Is there any specific type that meets this?

Comment: Now I find isinstance(ob, (type, types.ModuleType)), False for ob and True for both TestClass and TestModule. And thanks Pieters